# How do I change between orders? (Durmand, Whispers, Vigil)

Tags: guild-wars-2

At some point during the personal story the game forces you to choose one of three orders:

- Durmand priory
- Order of whispers
- Vigil

The [wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Order) says that once you've made a choice, you can change affiliation "with a little effort", but doesn't give more detail.

How do I exactly change between orders?

EDIT: Currently, I'm playing a human guardan, in case the method is race/profession specific.

Comment: You should specify which race, because the Asura definitely don't have any orders.

Comment: Really? I didn't know. From the wiki: "An order is a multi-racial organization which is dedicated to combating the awoken Elder Dragons". Asura must be the exception, then

Comment: Huh! Then maybe I just haven't gotten there yet, I figured it was race specific because I hadn't seen it.

Comment: @Tacroy: I can definitely confirm that I have been playing with an Asura and these orders have entered my personal story (around high teen levels).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR - **You can't change order.**

---

Before and shortly after game release there was rumors that you can change your order becouse of [old Wiki page about **Order**](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/index.php?title=Order&oldid=352602) that sayed that player "would be able to **change Order** with a little bit of effort".

It was written in disscusion on this page this information was mistake and "**choice seems to be tied into game mechanics**".

Source of this missunterstanding is [quotation from Ree Soesbee, GW2 Game Designer](http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/4304-interview-french-fansites-meet-stephane-cm-mondes-persistants/page__st__30#entry190210) who was missunderstanded as she said;

> The choice of an order is not compulsory, however, you can’t progress through the full extent of the storyline unless you do so. **You can change orders once you’ve chosen one – with a little effort** – but parts of the storyline are linked to the orders, so in order to see certain facets of the personal story, you will need to join one. That said, you can play the game without joining one if you truly choose to do so.

But true undesrtanding of this statement was explained [few posts later](http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/4304-interview-french-fansites-meet-stephane-cm-mondes-persistants/page__st__30#entry191526);

> You can get through the *all major areas* in game, but **not through the
>   whole story**. You can do dungeons/events level up and visit every part
>   of the world - except your personal story will stop progressing.

And;

> So I could play 99% through the story (but not finish it) with order
>   A, then **switch to order B**, and do 99% of its story, and then order C?
>
> **You won't be able to do that**.

Answer (score 3):

Once you choose an order, YOU CANNOT change to any other. That order is what your character's storyline will follow.

You can create a new character, and in that story choose a different order, but it will not change what the previous character's choice was.

Comment: Are you sure? The wiki link does mention changing is possible.

Comment: @Mac I'm not sure. Could you include your sources please?

Comment: My source is the game when it tells you that you CANNOT change what you choose for that character...

Answer (score 3):

Quoted directly from the Guild Wars 2 Wikia:

> Other players can help with another player's story but are not able to make choices which affect the outcome, though they can choose to accept the outcome as their own.

I suppose that by choosing another storyline, you can change your order, if your comrade chooses one that is different from your own. Unfortunately, I have not yet discover how to do that.

Comment: Are you sure this means you can _change_ your order? I understood it as you can accept the outcome as your own if you haven't made the decision yet.